# How to customize default auth login form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How do you customize the default login form in Django?

```
# demo_project/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('pages.urls')),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), # new
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), # new
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

<!-- templates/registration/login.html -->
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
```

Above code works but I need to customize that {{form.as_p}} Where is that form or can it be override? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 62):

you can overide default Authentication form

like this

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UsernameField

from django import forms


class UserLoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserLoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    username = UsernameField(widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'hello'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': '',
            'id': 'hi',
        }
))
```

in url.py you can pass this custom authentication form  like this

```
from django.contrib.auth import views

from myapp.forms import UserLoginForm
urlpatterns = [

    path(
        'login/',
        views.LoginView.as_view(
            template_name="login.html",
            authentication_form=UserLoginForm
            ),
        name='login'
)
]
```

also, you can override the login template

and customize the template as per you requirement

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="form-group">
        
        <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}
        {{ form.username.errors }}

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       
        <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.password.errors }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How can I change the default fields in login form?

Comment: @Nakul_Narayanan Exactly what I need. Thanks for your hard work!

Comment: @Nakul Narayanan can you provide documentation links as reference?

Comment: It nearly works.

You need to replace username = forms.EmailField by username = UsernameField

You also need to import UsernameField so you need to replace:
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

by

from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UsernameField


I tried to submit the change by got rejected...

Answer (score 12):

You can customise your form rendering by overriding/editing **templates/registration/login.html** as below.

*This is for example only you can change css styles and formatting as you want.*

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.username.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.username.id_for_label }}">Username:</label>
        {{ form.username }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.password.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.password.id_for_label }}">Password:</label>
        {{ form.password }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

*You may also loop over form's fields*

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
            {% if field.help_text %}
            <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

You could also check [more form rendering options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options)

Comment: do you know how to customize the login form ( adding fields ) ?

Answer (score 8):

From question, I assume you want to change the html template's look and feel instead of python forms class. In this case all you need to do is include input type fields with the matching names and ids attributes what default django-auth form expects. You can achieve this using following steps.

1. Render the template as you are rendering right now (using {{form.as_p}}).
2. Inspect elements and check user name, password and submit button's name and ids generated by default auth form.
3. Recreate same tags using your own custom style.

It comes something similar to below:

```
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="input" class="form-control" name="username" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Username" required >
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="inputPass" placeholder="Password" required>
  <button type="submit" style="opacity: 1 !important;">Login</button>
  <a href="/password_reset">Reset Password</a>
</form>
```

After this you can use your imagination and design the login form as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wrong, or incomplete at least. you will loose the automatic error management/display. And is not a recommended way to do it for various more reasons.