# Django Html İnput Field "> Character

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to shape up my login page form as per django. I'm facing an extra >" characters at the end of my entry fields.

There is the image error. See image below.

[image]

You might need to pay attention to right up corner of the input fields. Is there any idea, where is this "> came from ? Thanks for your time!

```html
<form method="POST"> {% csrf_token%}
    <div class="field">
        <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
        <input type="text" required placeholder="Email Adress" for="{{form.username}}">
    </div>
    <div class="field space">
        <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
        <input type="password" class="pass-key" required placeholder="Password" for="{{form.password}}">
        <span class="show">SHOW</span>
    </div>
    <div class="pass">
        <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
    </div>
</form>
```

There is the full code

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Somehow I got an error, so I comment the title, just uncomment to show -->
        <!-- <title>Transparent Login Form UI</title> -->
        <link href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="bg-img">
            <div class="content">
            <header>Welcome to Norga</header>
            <form method="POST"> {% csrf_token%}
                <div class="field">
                    <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                    <input type="text" required placeholder="Email Adress" for="{{form.username}}">
                    <!-- {{form.username}} -->
                </div>
                <div class="field space">
                    <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
                    <input type="password" class="pass-key" required placeholder="Password" for="{{form.password}}">
                    <!-- {{form.password}} -->
                    <span class="show">SHOW</span>
                </div>
                <div class="pass">
                    <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="login">
            Or login with</div>
            <div class="links">
                <div class="facebook">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"><span>Facebook</span></i>
                </div>
                <div class="instagram">
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram"><span>Instagram</span></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="signup">
                Don't have account?
                <a href="{% url 'account_createview' %}">Signup Now</a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="signup">
                Email verification
                <a href="{% url 'resend_email_verification' %}">Send Again</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    const pass_field = document.querySelector('.pass-key');
    const showBtn = document.querySelector('.show');
    showBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(pass_field.type === "password"){
    pass_field.type = "text";
    showBtn.textContent = "HIDE";
    showBtn.style.color = "#3498db";
    }else{
    pass_field.type = "password";
    showBtn.textContent = "SHOW";
    showBtn.style.color = "#222";
    }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly does this question have to do with Python?

Comment: Can you show the source-code for this part of the loaded html page.

Comment: `{{form.<field_name>}}` will render the entire input tag for the field, you need to either replace your input tags with the output from the form fields or use the correct attributes from the fields in your custom html. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Comment: I added the full code pf my template. Iain; I'm not sure where I'm wrong at my code. Can you describe it with more detail.

Comment: The 'for' that you are using in input has to be used in other tag like label: <label for="fname">First name:</label> <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">

Comment: Allright but how can I get rid of the >" characters at the end of my entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem with re-coding my login views. I was using the django auth_views.LoginView , however it was not fit to my html scale in that way. Therefore, I came up with a new form in forms.py file and change my urls in accordance with the url in the below.

There is the solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55369645/how-to-customize-default-auth-login-form-in-django/55369791) for the form and custimizing the loginview and there is my new form in html file in the below;

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token%}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                {{ form.username.errors }}
                {{ form.password.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                {{ form.username }}
            </div>
            <div class="field space">
                <span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
                {{ form.password }}
                <span class="show">SHOW</span>
            </div>
            <div class="pass">
                <a href="#">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <input type="submit" value="LOGIN">
            </div>
        </form>
```